# Database solution for a medical laboratory website?

Tags: php, html, database, excel, csv

I'm a beginner web developer trying to build my portfolio by doing my father's website (he owns a medical laboratory). Such sites have a test catalog (as in medical tests that can be ordered) and sometimes what's available changes from week to week, like a fancy restaurant menu. Some sites like amsreferencelab have a link to download their latest catalog as a PDF; simple enough.

But what my dad wants is something more like http://mayomedicallaboratories.com where you can browse alphabetically by disease or by test name. What's more, it looks like the mayo site has the unordered list items change dynamically when a new database (maybe an Excel spreadsheet?) is uploaded to their server, and those additions automatically get placed into their proper letter (for example, a new test starting with "L" gets put as a new unordered list item under the "L" page) and there's even a "NEW TESTS" link that has new tests uploaded recently.

Do you guys have a general idea of how to go about this? I've tried using a CSV to table code snippet on [my dad's website](http://kspath.com/test.html) so far but the CSV format is snarly; my dad wants to be able to upload an Excel spreadsheet and have that be an HTML table but I don't think that's how Mayo's doing it. How do you think Mayo goes about this?

Comment: does not sound like a beginner's project. the legal ramifications of not getting security correct would destroy the business

Comment: This is unfortunately too broad a question for here, but you may garner some basic guidance in the comments.

Comment: I know you can parse an Excel spreadsheet in Java with Apache POI. And that you should do your mockup on a local host, not a live server.

Comment: You are probably best served by looking at an existing eCommerce software package.  There are lots of them out there to choose from.  Too general of a question for SO though.

Comment: @halfer so what site would you suggest asking these types of questions?

Comment: @Dagon "destroy the business" is a bit dramatic; this isn't personal records or anything like that; just simply a constantly changing catalog of the types of tests hospitals can order. There's not even going to be an ordering functionality on the website, just browsing.

Comment: I've added an answer prior to this question being put on hold - don't take it as evidence that design queries are on-topic `;-)`. I am not aware of a Q&A site that accepts design questions, though there is likely one out there somewhere...

Comment: even if the site itself does not deal with personal information, a flaw in it could give access to the server  .... I'm all for learning by building something, but start with a personal site, not a business related one. A professional business should have a professionally built site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will need to convert any existing spreadsheet you have to relational data, perhaps something like MySQL. That means that first you'll need to design a database layout, with tables, columns, types and foreign key constraints. Read up about normalisation - it's a fancy way of reducing data duplication by using separate tables.

Once the data is available in a relational database, you can create HTML pages to render it in whatever tabular format you like. These will require `SELECT` queries using a database library, so you'll need to learn SQL as well. This will usually involve either the PDO or MySQLi libraries.

A lookup index (diseases beginning with letter 'A', for example) uses a simple `SELECT ... LIKE` query. Additionally, each page may be paginated.

From there, you'll likely want to edit the data, so you'll need a users table, and sessions to maintain state across pages. The edit feature itself will be a PHP page that issues `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries to write to the database. Make sure password columns are hashed and salted, and don't do this yourself - there are libraries available for this that are security-tested.

It is quite possible to write a system that allows a spreadsheet (or CSV file) to be uploaded and parsed for data, but a proper online editing system is usually better. This has the added advantage of reducing "spreadsheet dependency", in which enterprises trap their data inside proprietary desktop applications, which in turn makes it difficult to reuse outside of its immediate purpose.

One of the comments correctly indicates that there are a number of security issues to be aware of - I would say SQL injection and Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) are the ones you most need to look out for. If you are handling any type of personal information, don't take the project on. If not, go for it, but take regular database backups; most web hosts allow you to configure this, either through cPanel or cron.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Again, there's no personal information being dealt with here, and if worse comes to worse, I can simply provide a pdf link to the latest catalog (like many other laboratory websites do) and I could still play around with the files offline and learn something about building databases as it relates to web development. Sorry about this being "too general" for Stackoverflow; I figured this got into enough coding nitty-gritty that my question wouldn't ruffle the take-it-somewhere-else feathers that it did. Thanks again.

Comment: No probs. I don't think any feathers have been ruffled - it's worth bearing in mind that this site gets about a million visitors a day, many of them with questions lacking any research at all (I don't mean to include yours in that category - you've clearly put in prior thought). Thus, comments that explain the posting guidelines are sometimes a bit more robust than would be ideal `:)`.

Comment: By the way, if you are looking to improve your PHP skills, I'm currently recommending [Codecademy's PHP track](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) - it's free. Not affiliated to them, just like the interactivity of the course.

Comment: Very good idea; I was just about to start it, too. Not a bad language to learn!